# modulo argparse fallo jupyter-notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, anaconda, anaconda3, argparse

Hola alguien sabe porque me da este error al hacer argumentos con argparse, estoy trabajando en jupyter notebook en anaconda:

**codigo**:

```
from shodan import Shodan
import argparse
import sys

parser =argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-q", "--query", help="Busqueda")
parser.add_argument("-a","--api", help="Tu api")
parser=parser.parse_args()
```

Al ejecutar esto me da este error:

usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [-q QUERY] [-a API]
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -f /home/thor/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-370e2561-a3e2-4bd2-a099-d3d53c04059e.json

An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2

Answer (score 0):

No he podido reproducir el error que te da.

Revisando en la siguiente pregunta de stackoverflow: [How to fix ipykernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments in jupyter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48796169/how-to-fix-ipykernel-launcher-py-error-unrecognized-arguments-in-jupyter) (Cómo arreglar el error de argumentos no reconocidos en jupyter ipykernel_launcher.py), he podido leer que al parecer podría haber un conflicto con el módulo `argparse` y `jupyter`.

Justamente estás usando `argparse` haciendo un `import` de él.

Por la forma de tratar los argumentos, mandan cambiar **de**:

```
parser = parser.parse_args()
```

**A**:

```
parser = parser.parse_args(argv[1:])
```

Espero ayudarte.